# Circular Slider/progressBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement a circular slider for a music player.

but the packages like sleek_circular_slider (https://github.com/matthewfx/sleek_circular_slider) and other packages like this are not suitable .

means for example the package above is very good in change the position but it is not possible to use it as a progressBar to show currently music duration.

I want a circular slider like default flutter Slider.
because it has both onChanged method and value property which is responsible for currently position.
but unfortunately I think there is not package in flutter to have both parameters.
Thanks .

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_circular_slider

Comment: I test that but it is not possible to use `position` parameter inside SingleCircularSlider to use it as a progressBar and change currently value based on music player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced with the similar challenge, I ended up creating a [custom flare animation](https://rive.app/a/garadget/files/flare/garage). The progress can then be set by the animation controller to any frame.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to share your code,  because I didn't use flare animation before.

Comment: In my stetefull widget I have 

`final DoorAnimationController animationController = DoorAnimationController();`

Then in build method there is:
`FlareActor(
    "assets/animations/garage-door.flr",
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    controller: animationController,
)`

My DoorAnimationControllere extends FlareController and has a lot of specifics related to my application, but the point is to update the current time in the animation on each frame depending on what the current progress is. This is done in advance function.

Comment: My results are based on dissecting this sample: https://github.com/2d-inc/Flare-Flutter/tree/master/example/slider